# image doesn't show after render animation blender 2.8

Tags: animation, 2d, blender

i have some problem with background rendering in blender 2d!
i have some simple animation, and i use a picture as a background

[image]

and when i try to render animation

[image]

i have an empty background. i have my animation on empty white background

[image]

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try enabling "import image as a plane" addon in edit/ preferences.